# How to automatically create TypeScript or Flow definitions for Stampit objects?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, flowtype, stampit.js

The Stampit javascript library is awesome for composing JS object factories using behavior prototypes (see https://github.com/stampit-org/stampit).  But after creating objects from a stamp that may have been exported from a module, the intellisense in VC Code falls short, and for these type of composed objects, it would be really nice to see their properties and methods.

Note that it possible to manually create definitions in Flow or Typescript (*.d.ts files) but that approach can be tedious and error-prone.  Instead of manually creating definitions, could I use a tool or tools to accomplish it automatically?

For example, given these stripped-down Stamps (Fighter, Mage, Paladin):

```
const Fighter = stampit(Character, { // inheriting
  props: {
      stamina: 100
      },
  methods: {
      fight() {}
})

const Mage = stampit(Character, { // inheriting
  props: {
    mana: 100
  },
  methods: {
    cast() {}
  }
})

const Paladin = stampit(Mage, Fighter)  // composed
```

And, then somewhere, in another javascript file, where a Paladin is to be created …

```
const paladin :Paladin = createPaladin() // notice :Paladin

// would like intellisense in VC Code to show me possible methods

paladin.cast()
```

So, instead of manually creating the definition file (below), the tool(s) would auto-generate using the Stampit code for Paladin(or any stamps) - (Note: this could be done for Flow but probably prefer TS since the interface and concrete class can have the same name):

```
interface Paladin {
    // Fighter
    stamina: number,
    fight(),

    // Mage 
    mana: string,
    cast()
}
```

That would allow, in VS Code at least, to popup a list of valid methods using intellisense, after typing dot (.):

```
paladin.<show cast() and fight() methods on popup>
```

Comment: Though it definitely wouldn't be trivial, generics and modern features like mapped types could be used to intelligently infer types that do what you want to do. Though I'm not really sure if it would be worth it. You might have less trouble using the built-in class model, where there are still patterns that enable mixin-like behaviors and such. That, or you could not use inheritance at all, opting for factory functions and composing objects together.

Comment: Tools/IDEs do support classes syntax very well. Classes exists for about 50 years now. Stamps, even being a simpler syntax, exist for 5 years only. IDEs yet to have proper stamp syntax support.

Comment: The solution could be a plugin but could run outside an IDE. Such a plugin would need to parse stampit syntax to extract a definition.

Comment: Have you checked @types/stampit?